# Scroll the view upto last entry

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms.entry

I am doing an app in which i have to submit data having 8 entries one by one in a stack. I used the scrollview.But when the user clicks on first entry the keypad will appear and screen scrolls.Then the user can see the second entry and fill the data.

But after coming to fourth entry or fifth entry the scrolls gets stopped.As a result the user cannot see the the next entry without closing the keypad.

Can anyone please give a solution to my problem.I tried adding the scrollview to the entire screen also.

Thanks in Advance.

Here is my code:

```
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="First Name"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="Last Name"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="Email"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="Mobile Number"/>
      <Label Text="Address" FontSize="15"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="House Number"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="Street"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="City"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="Street"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="State"/>
      <Entry PlaceHolder="Country"/>
      <Button Text="Submit"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Share your code. so, anyone can identify your issue.

Comment: Hi @PavanVParekh I updated my question please check and provide a solution.There is a </ScrollView> at the end of the code.

Comment: It looks perfect. provide whole code. So, I can identify the actual issue.

Comment: There is no mode code Pavan.This is the simple code in a page and a clicked event for the submit button

Comment: If your all code in ScrollView then it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

> But after coming to fourth entry or fifth entry the scrolls gets stopped.As a result the user cannot see the the next entry without closing the keypad.

Please try using `WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize` for your Activity's setting:

Example:

```
[Activity(Label = "Demo", MainLauncher = true,WindowSoftInputMode =SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    ...
}
```

For details please refer to `Specify How Your UI Should Respond` session of [Handling Input Method Visiblity](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html#Respond)

Comment: It also doesn't worked Elvis.And also i updated my Xamarin.Forms package but no use.